# How can I extract only the text inside anchor-tags with beatifulsoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm currently working on my first web scraping app, for which I use BeautifulSoup. It all works nicely in spite of the difficult time I'm having with the website I'm scraping which doesn't use class names for its HTML elements.

Still with the help of StackOverflow and the documentation I'm getting further and further until now where I think I'm doing the right thing, but with I'm getting an error. The problem I'm trying to solve is to get the text within an a-tag inside of a table on the website. ([www.footballbettingtips.org](http://www.footballbettingtips.org)).

Altough I can get the full a-tag, for example:

**href="/tips/2021-07-06/849719.html" title="Betting Tips - Keflavik W. - Thor Akureyri W.">***Keflavik W. - Thor Akureyri W.***** </ a>

I only want the text: **Keflavik W. - Thor Akureyri W.**.

This is my code:

```
source = requests.get(URL, headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

# De info dat ik wil hebben: wedstrijden, tijd, voorspellingen & quotering
table = soup.find("table",{"class":"results"})
# print(table.prettify())

#dit zijn alle rijen met info over de wedstrijden
rows = table.findChildren('tr')
numb_rows = len(rows)
#dit is de hoeveelheid rijen met wedstrijdinfo + naam competitie van vandaag
# print(numb_rows)
all_games = []

for row in rows:
    a_tag = row.a.get_text()
    print(a_tag)

    for strong_tag in row.find_all('strong'):      
        prediction = strong_tag.text
        all_games.append(prediction)
```

and this part is giving me and error:

```
for row in rows:
    a_tag = row.a.get_text()
    print(a_tag)
```

error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/Jente/Desktop/Webscraping/webscraping.py", line 28, in 
a_tag = row.a.get_text()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

I don't know how to solve this because with the documentation in mind this should be working to only get the text. I've tried a lot of things like not using a for-loop, the getText() method, and a lot of other ways to avoid the error.

I hope someone knows where and how this went wrong in my case and helps me out here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the table in pandas DataFrame you can use next example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0"
}

url = "https://www.footballbettingtips.org/tips/2021-07-06.html"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")

data = []
for tr in soup.select("tr:not(:has(th))"):
    tds = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.select("td")]
    if len(tds) != 7:
        continue
    data.append([tr.find_previous("h4").get_text(strip=True), *tds[:6]])

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data, columns=["League", "Time", "Match", "1", "X", "2", "Tip"]
)
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

```
                          League   Time                                              Match      1      X      2  Tip
0           AFC Champions League  10:00                        Cerezo Osaka - Guangzhou FC   1.06   9.60  34.50  4:0
1           AFC Champions League  14:00                               Port FC - Kitchee SC   1.96   3.43   3.60  0:2
2            Aus. NPL Queensland  09:30     Sunshine Coast Wanderers - Brisbane Roar Youth   7.20   5.95   1.28  1:2
3            Aus. NPL Queensland  09:30                  Peninsula Power - Redlands United   1.05  10.50  23.50  3:0
4           Brazilian Paranaense  18:20                          Operario PR - Londrina PR   1.99   2.76   4.63  1:2
5              Brazilian Serie A  22:30                       Santos - Atletico Paranaense   2.29   3.05   3.38  1:1
6              Brazilian Serie B  22:00                                 Ponte Preta - Avai   2.63   2.81   2.83  0:2
7              Brazilian Serie B  22:00                             Cruzeiro - Coritiba PR   2.30   2.93   3.18  2:0
8       Cambodian Premier League  11:00                     Svay Rieng FC - Cambodia Tiger   1.44   4.72   5.50  2:0
9               Champions League  16:00                 HJK Helsinki - Buducnost Podgorica   1.39   4.98   7.65  3:1
10              Champions League  16:00                Flora Tallinn - Hibernians FC Paola   1.64   3.90   5.50  0:0
11              Champions League  16:00                     Ferencvárosi TC - KF Prishtina   1.15   8.00  18.00  2:1
12              Champions League  17:00                        Zalgiris Vilnius - Linfield   1.90   3.65   4.00  2:0
13              Champions League  17:00                        CFR Cluj - Borac Banja Luka   1.18   6.75  17.50  1:1
14              Champions League  17:30                 CS Fola Esch - Lincoln Red Imps FC   1.39   4.92   8.00  4:0
15              Champions League  18:00                          Skendija Tetovo - NŠ Mura   2.79   3.25   2.60  2:1
16               Club Friendlies  09:00                            Kortrijk - Valenciennes   1.87   3.78   3.45  0:1
17             Euro Championship  19:00                                      Italy - Spain   2.45   3.17   3.07  0:0
18      Europa Conference League  15:45                          Mosta FC - Spartak Trnava   5.75   4.38   1.48  1:2
19      Europa Conference League  15:50                    Mons Calpe SC - FC Santa Coloma   2.37   3.27   2.85  2:1
20      Europa Conference League  18:30                             FK Podgorica - FK Laci   2.02   3.42   3.42  2:0
21      Finnish Kakkonen Group B  15:30             Tampereen Ilves II - FC Honka Akatemia   2.16   3.98   2.66  1:1
22                      Gold Cup  20:30                Trinidad and Tobago - French Guiana   1.24   5.50  11.00  4:1
23                      Gold Cup  23:00                                    Haiti - Bermuda   1.35   4.90   7.25  2:0
24      Icelandic Úrvalsdeild W.  18:00                     Keflavik W. - Thor Akureyri W.   2.49   3.57   2.46  1:2
25      Icelandic Úrvalsdeild W.  18:00        Fylkir Reykjavik W. - IBV Vestmannaeyjar W.   1.96   3.55   3.35  2:0
26      Icelandic Úrvalsdeild W.  18:00                        Stjarnan W. - Tindastoll W.   1.52   4.33   4.98  3:0
27      Icelandic Úrvalsdeild W.  20:00                    Selfoss W. - Valur Reykjavik W.   4.83   4.45   1.52  2:3
28      Icelandic Úrvalsdeild W.  20:00              Throttur Reykjavik W. - Breidablik W.   8.75   7.15   1.20  1:3
29            Iranian Pro League  14:30             Machine Sazi Tabriz - Mes Rafsanjan FC   5.65   3.05   1.74  0:1

...
```

And saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you for this! I've tried to accomplish this in the past few days, but every stap was really difficult. I'm still a Python beginner and especially Beautfifulsoup is really difficult for me. I try to understand your code and I've tried Pandas and Dataframe before but I couldn't figure it out. The first thing I don't understand is what this does:   soup.select("tr:not(:has(th))")   what does it mean? And also why is this in square brackets?:  [tr.find_previous("h4").get_text(strip=True), *tds[:6] I hope you can explain your code a little bit :) Thanks anyways!

Comment: @Thelegend27 The `"tr:not(:has(th))"` is CSS selector. It means select all `<tr>` tags which don't contain `<th>` tags. `[tr.find_previous("h4").get_text(strip=True), *tds[:6]]` will create a list where first element is league name and next six elements are Time, Match,1,X,2 and Tip elements.

Comment: Alright! Thank you for that. I will dive into the documentation once more to learn more about the CSS selectors but also the syntax isn't really readable for me (unfamiliar) so thats also why I asked you to explain it a bit haha. Anyways, I can go on with my project.

Comment: @Thelegend27 Some good doc about CSS selectors: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp  It's useful to know it if you want do more web-scraping. Also, regex is your friend too ;)